# Using Ansible in Azure to assign user assigned managed identities (UAMI) to VMs

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-managed-identity

I have an user assigned managed identity (UAMI) in my Azure environment, and I'm able to programmatically assign it to whichever VM I choose with the following azure-cli command:

```
az vm identity assign --ids [Resource ID of VM] --identities [Resource ID of UAMI]
```

My question now is there a way to do this in Ansible? When I look at the "azure_rm_virtualmachine" module documentation, it doesn't appear there's a way to assign a UAMI at VM creation time; even though there IS functionality to enable a system-managed identity.

I've been looking at the "azure_rm_roleassignment" documentation, but despite every way I try to plug in the IDs for my VM and UAMI, Ansible returns with some sort of error every time. For instance, with the following:

```
  - name: Create a role assignment
    azure_rm_roleassignment:
      scope: "/subscriptions/{{ subscriptionID }}/"
      assignee_object_id: "{{ VMresourceID }}"
      role_definition_id:
        "{{ UAMIresourceID }}"
```

Error message is: "Error creating role assignment: Azure Error: InvalidPrincipalId\nMessage: The Principal ID 'XXX' is not valid. Principal ID must be a GUID."

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: kindly update the OP with non-sensitive error info ?

Comment: @error404 Done! :-D

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @CharlesXu See comments below

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you set the `assignee_object_id` with the VM resource ID, I think it's the problem. No matter you choose the system-assigned or user-assigned managed identity, the `assignee_object_id` should be the object Id of it, not the resource Id. You can get object ID via the CLI command:

```
az vm identity show -g group_name -n vm_name --query principalId -o tsv
```

See more details about the [`assignee_object_id`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_roleassignment_module.html#parameter-assignee_object_id).

Comment: When I ran 'az vm identity show -g [RG] -n [ServerName]', it had no output. But after some further digging, I don't think this ansible module is what I'm looking for. I've tried setting the assignee_object_id = vmID (from 'vm show --ids [ResourceID] --query vmId'), and role_definition_id = /subscriptions/{{ subID }}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{{ objIDofUAMI }}, but then I get the error "The specified role definition with ID X does not exist

Comment: This module appears to be just for assigning a role (i.e. a set of permissions in Azure) to an identity (be it system-managed or UAMI). NOT for simply assigning an identity to something like a VM. There doesn't seem to be any other ansible module that assigns UAMIs to VMs either, so I think I'm gonna have to find another way

Comment: @sirjames2004 The ansible module is related to the CLI command `az vm identity assign`. The `assignee_object_id` needs the VM identity object Id, not the VM resource Id. And if you want to use the VM identity, you need to enable the VM identity first. If not, the command `az vm identity show` give the empty output.

Comment: The principalId of a VM (i.e. VM identity object Id) won't be set unless the SYSTEM-managed identity of that VM is enabled, which is what I've bee trying to avoid doing

Comment: @sirjames2004 The principal Id is also needed even if you user user-assigned managed identity.

Comment: When I use the CLI to run 'az vm identity assign --ids [Resource ID of VM] --identities [Resource ID of UAMI]', it's able to successfully assign the UAMI to the VM without the system-assigned identity being enabled; implying that this shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @sirjames2004 The parameter `identities` need the principal Id, not the resource ID.

Comment: The CLI cmd does work as I've detailed above; with both the ResourceID of the VM and the ResourceID of the UAMI, AND without enabling the system-managed identity of the VM. Have you tried testing this on you end yet?

Comment: @sirjames2004 Why don't you understand it? It's not the VM system-managed identity. It's the user-managed identity. They are both the managed identity. Both of them use the principal ID. As you show in your answer `my_server_reg.ansible_facts.azure_vm.identity.principalId`, it's the identity principal ID.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that ansible currently supports a way to assign an UAMI to a VM; as with `az vm identity assign --ids [Resource ID of VM] --identities [Resource ID of UAMI]` in the CLI. Thus, as a stop-gap, we've opted to just go with system-managed identities for the time being. I've added the following to the VM creation in ansible:

```
azure_rm_virtualmachine:
  vm_identity: SystemAssigned
register: my_server_reg
```

Then the following to my role assignment:

```
azure_rm_roleassignment:
  scope: "/subscriptions/{{ subscription_id }}/"
  assignee_object_id: "{{ my_server_reg.ansible_facts.azure_vm.identity.principalId }}"
  role_definition_id:
        "/subscriptions/{{ subscription_id }}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{{ blob_reader_roledef_id }}"
```

It'll be more cumbersome to manage, but I'm not seeing any other alternatives at this point in time.